# loop html statements using php

Tags: php, html

This is my code. It is actually an html file. I want to loop those statements using php so that I can have that paragraph in my html page repeated for any number of times. Please help

```
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){

        <li>
            <div class="imgholder"><img src="images/demo/imgl.gif" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="latestnews">
                <h2>Text !</h2>
                <p>Text 2</p>
            </div>
            <br class="clear" />
        </li> 
    }
?>
```

Comment: you need to `echo` the HTML inside php

Comment: can u show the code? plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `echo` the HTML inside php:

```
<?php

        for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
        {

echo          '<li>
            <div class="imgholder"><img src="images/demo/imgl.gif" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="latestnews">
              <h2>Text !</h2>
              <p>Text 2</p>
            </div>
            <br class="clear" />
          </li>'; 
    }
           ?>
```

Or you could just separate the HTML and php like:

```
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
    { ?>

        <li>
        <div class="imgholder"><img src="images/demo/imgl.gif" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="latestnews">
          <h2>Text !</h2>
          <p>Text 2</p>
        </div>
        <br class="clear" />
      </li> 
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanku sir... that worked.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Close Php tag after braces, you can also write HTML in single Quotes.

```
     <?php
    for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
    {
    ?>
     <li>
      <div class="imgholder"><img src="images/demo/imgl.gif" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="latestnews">
       <h2>Text !</h2>
       <p>Text 2</p>
        </div>
        <br class="clear" />
       </li>
   <?php
       }
    ?>
```